# Publish only changes from stored procedures and views from one database to another in Azure Repos

Tags: version-control, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-repos

I have created a database project in visual studio that includes schemas, tables, stored procedures and tables. I've added them to source control in Azure Repos. I want to publish only the stored procedures and views to another database(they have the same table schemas).

When the project builds in azure pipeline it would create the build for all the database objects and the release pipeline would publish these changes to the database. Is there any way to exclude the tables and only build and publish stored procedures and views?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure DevOps, you can go to the release pipeline and set the Additional SqlPackage.exe Arguments parameter as /p:ExcludeObjectTypes=Tables

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways

1. As you are saying the second target database already have the same tables present then run SQLPackage.exe in the release with parameter /p:CreateNewDatabase=False, that would mean that it will try to update the database, and will only add objects ( tables, sps, views, roles, users etc.) which are not present or update the objects (tables, sps, views, roles, users etc.) which are different.
2. If you think your tables may be different, and you don't want them to be updated and excluded altogether, then update the .sqlproj file as part of build to have the build action as none instead of build  `<None Include="Schema Objects\Schemas\dbo\Tables\tablename.sql" />`, 
   but do note if tables are referenced in stored procedures and/or views then **build will fail**.

Best approach is first one.

Comment: I also want modified stored procedures and views to be updated in the database as well, not just the newly created ones.  Is this possible?

Comment: yes it will update stored procedures and views if they are different, updated the answer as well.